# Problems with DNN and Telerik - Could not load type

Tags: telerik, dotnetnuke

I have problem with building DNN portal which have TELERIK included.
Problem is bellow:
Error   107 Could not load type 'DNNMasters.CB.Telerik.WebControls.Spell.DialogHandler'.    D:\DNN\DNN-5.4.04\DesktopModules\DNNMasters.CB.ArticleBrowser\RadControls\Spell\Telerik.Spell.DialogHandler.aspx    1

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, Telerik.WebControls is the namespace used for the old ASP.NET version of the Telerik controls. The AJAX Telerik controls come with DotNetNuke distributions 5.2.0 or later as [this page](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/dnn-partnership.aspx) says, my recommendation is to switch to them.